# Convert pasted text into single line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox

So I have a textbox where I want an address to be stored, but as a single line. To get the address in there I will always do a copy and paste, and the issue is that where I copy it from, it is multiline, so when I paste it, it only shows the first line. I know I can change it into a multiline textbox and then use backspace to make it one line, but I'm just wondering if there is a way I can just make it single line with code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText().Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

Comment: Where does the yourAddrStr come from? What I'm doing is pasting it directly into the textbox.

Comment: @ChristopherBonilla You're the only one who can answer the question where yourAddrStr comes from. Where did you get the address?

Comment: @ChristopherBonilla In that case, replace yourAddStr to Clipboard.GetText()

Comment: Worked perfectly, just one issue: there is a possibility that I have to manually enter the address, and this ALWAYS takes the pasted text, how do I access the paste event? so that this only happens when pasted?

Answer (score 7):

Try,

```
textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text.Replace("\r\n", " ");
```

EDIT:

```
String singleLine=multiLine.Replace("\r\n"," ");
```

Comment: Why is the first textbox 1 and the second textbox2?

Comment: @ChristopherBonilla - This is for your reference. You may change it. Don't forget the Replace is a method of String class and you can use it with string object.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove '\n' characters from the input and '\r' as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of obvious, isn't it? Why don't you write a line of code explaining HOW?

Comment: i didn't thought spoon feeding code was so important as much as giving idea.

Comment: I would love to be spoon fed please

Comment: But you already got the answer. Choose one of them. But among all, i would replace \r and \n with blank rather than a space, what do u think?

Comment: yes, it will put a space. On second thought, if each lines do not have space at the beginning and end, removing new lines would cause them to stick with each other without any space which would look bad. Depends on how you want it. I'd also Trim() it before replacing with spaces.